# Jmeter JMS Publisher&Consumer samplers duplicate transaction in Report

Tags: jmeter, jms

I have a test with jms subscriber and publisher to queue

After loadtest through cli i see duplicated transactions in report, total number of executed sampler isn't like the expected hence load is 2x

[Pic from summary report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2GhX.png)

Thread group has a specified life time and loop count 1, action after sampler error - continue

What could be cause?

---

Thread group has enabled flag Same user on each iteration and Number of threads 1620

Sampler's parent is throughput controller with throughput 0.00238 and flag Per User

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using [Transaction Controllers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-transaction-controller) which generate virtual artificial Sample Results.

Transaction Controller is used to measure cumulative execution time of its children execution by generating an extra sample result.

You can exclude the "children" by generating [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) and exporting only transaction controllers you're interested in

[image]

or just exclude all sample results with `-0`, `-1` etc. postfixes by setting the `jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter` property to `^((?!-).)*(-success|-failure)?$`

More information: [Reporting Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#reporting)

Comment: I used throughput controller though
Does it have same behavior? This doesn't happen during debug run for short time period so i thought there could be some logical error